# Why is this question offtopic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How to download a file from server using SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427553/how-to-download-a-file-from-server-using-ssh)

It seems to be a common question in the SSH tag. (like any other)

Comment: It's not a programming question.

Comment: but there are many other questions that are not related to programming either - but not closed (just browse ssh tag)

Comment: that's a different question, not the one you are asking ...

Comment: Are those questions relatively new in time or are they very old?

Comment: If you want to point them out I'm sure they will get closed too.

Comment: I've edited in existing explanations from the question since those clearly did not satisfy OP. @OstapB. please review that edit and update if you feel necessary.

Comment: @Alexei Not really sure what you were thinking with that last edit. You know that answers don't belong in questions....

Comment: @CodyGray those are not answers, it is information OP presumably *already had* about the post. I know that it is somewhat putting words in OP's mouth but on other hand assuming that they are not able to read and comprehend comments to linked question seem even more offensive... So I though they clearly looking for some *other* explanation compared to what they already seen on the linked question. But undoing that edit is fine by me - there is no way to actually know what additional info OP was trying to get.

Comment: @CodyGray I voted "unclear" instead to let OP edit the question to clarify what they looking for.

Comment: @Alexei I think you are perhaps reading too much into this. Obviously, Stack Overflow gets a *lot* of users who do not understand why general computer-usage questions are off-topic. If they did understand that, they probably wouldn't ask so many of them here. They may well have read the comments you cited, but not understood why they were making the claim that they were. Heck, I work with people who think it's "programming" any time you have a console window on your screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have explained questions relating to use of software (in this case the command line program `ssh`) is off topic here (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) except where it has to do with a specific programming problem where `ssh` is also commonly used (especially with scripting languages). This is standard across the whole Stackexchange network.

Many of the questions with the `ssh` tag actually have to do with integrating it in programming frameworks.

Of course some problematic posts (question and answers) do slip through the cracks sometimes. You are more then welcome to flag them, that's what flagging is for.